# Error: type Login is not a member of Object controller.Application(Play FrameWork)

Tags: java, playframework

I was practicing with [ZenTask (JavaGuided)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide1) on Play FrameWork with IntelliJ. I followed the steps exactly as outlined but I keep getting this annoying error:

```
"Type Login is not a member of Object controller.Application".
```

Please help identify the error.I find this framework extremely buggy and frustrating.

Complete Error Message:

```
Error:(24, 196) type Login is not a member of object controllers.Application
class login extends BaseScalaTemplate[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable,Format[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable]](play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat) with play.twirl.api.Template1[Form[Application.Login],play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable] {
Error:(27, 43) type Login is not a member of object controllers.Application
  def apply/*1.2*/(form: Form[Application.Login]):play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = {
Error:(71, 36) type Login is not a member of object controllers.Application
  def render(form:Form[Application.Login]): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = apply(form)
Error:(73, 28) type Login is not a member of object controllers.Application
  def f:((Form[Application.Login]) => play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable) = (form) => apply(form)
```

And here is my code:

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public String email;
    public String name;
    public String password;

    public User(String email, String name, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

   public  Finder<String,User> find = new Finder<String,User>(
            String.class, User.class
    );

    public  User authenticate(String email, String password) {
        return find.where().eq("email", email)
                .eq("password", password).findUnique();
    }
}
```

The controller: `form` and `loginForm` are highlighted as errors in `render(form(Login.class)))`  and `render(loginForm))`:

```
package controllers;

import models.User;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.index;
import views.html.login;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("hello"));
    }

    public Result login() {
        return ok(login.render(form(Login.class)));
    }

    public  Result authenticate() {
        Form<User> loginForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
        } else {
            session().clear();
            session("email", loginForm.get().email);
            return redirect(
                    routes.Application.index()
            );
        }
    }

    public class Login {
        public String email;
        public String password;
        public User user;

        public String validate() {
            user.authenticate(email, password);
            if (user == null) {
                return "Invalid user or password";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Views: Login highlighted as error.

```
@(form: Form[Application.Login])
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zentasks</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/login.css")">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="@routes.Application.index" id="logo"><span>Zen</span>tasks</a>
        </header>

        @helper.form(routes.Application.authenticate) {
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
            @if(form.hasGlobalErrors) {
                <p class="error">
                @form.globalError.message
                </p>
            }

            <p>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="@form("email").value">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </p>
        }

    </body>
</html>
```

Route:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /login                      controllers.Application.login()
POST    /login                      controllers.Application.authenticate()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: Which version of play are you using? And you are looking into a documentation for play 2.1.0.

Comment: I'm using version 2.5.I used the documentation of 2.1.0 because apparently they don't have the  ZenTask (JavaGuided) for 2.5.x users.

Comment: You can have a look into the migration guides because quite a lot of things have changed since 2.1. My best guess is that your routes is expecting static methods on the controllers but on 2.5 the controllers are injected on the routes and you have to map the actions like this `@controllers.Mycontroller.myAction()`.

Comment: Okay thanks.I will look at that .